# How to find particular text with colon in the output whose object type is <None> in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to find the solution of problem in which i have to find the certain parameter. PFB the output :

```
 Usage 203 (0xcb), Page 0x1
    (Generic Desktop device, Unknown usage)
        bit_field: 2
        data_index: 2
        designator_index: 0
        is_absolute: 1
        is_alias: 0
        is_button: True
        is_designator_range: 0
        is_range: 0
        is_string_range: 0
        is_value: False
        link_collection: 3
        link_usage: 13 (0xd)
        link_usage_page: 1 (0x1)
        report_id: 10
        string_index: 0

    Usage 203 (0xcb), Page 0x1
    (Generic Desktop device, Unknown usage)
        bit_field: 2
        data_index: 3
        designator_index: 0
        is_absolute: 1
        is_alias: 0
        is_button: True
        is_designator_range: 0
        is_range: 0
        is_string_range: 0
        is_value: False
        link_collection: 4
        link_usage: 13 (0xd)
        link_usage_page: 1 (0x1)
        report_id: 28
        string_index: 0

    Usage 203 (0xcb), Page 0x1
    (Generic Desktop device, Unknown usage)
        bit_field: 2
        data_index: 4
        designator_index: 0
        is_absolute: 1
        is_alias: 0
        is_button: True
        is_designator_range: 0
        is_range: 0
        is_string_range: 0
        is_value: False
        link_collection: 5
        link_usage: 13 (0xd)
        link_usage_page: 1 (0x1)
        report_id: 19
```

This is the output i am getting after running some operation.In this I have to find report_id: 28 .In the output if script find report_id: 28 then its pass otherwise its failed.

```
Suppose this output got stored in ABC whose type is -<type 'NoneType'>

for l in ABC:
    if "report_id: 28" in l:  
        print("Passed")
    else:
        print("Failed")
```

My question is as below: 1) How i will find report_id: 28 and print pass

Comment: could you just grep for that string? grep "report_id: 28" ABC

Comment: Will you elaborate little ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how those values are stored.

If it's a simple text file then you have to load and read the text file first, with for example:

```
with open("yourtextfile.txt", r) as myfile:
```

and read the file line by line:

```
readlines = myfile.readlines()
```

and iterate through the lines:

```
if report_id: 28 in readlines:
    print("Passed")
else:
    print("Failed")
```

But based on the output you posted, the texts may be stored as Python dictionary or as a custom object. If it's a dictionary named abc then you can do:

```
if abc["report_id"] == 28:
    print("Passed")
else:
    print("Failed")
```

If it's a custom object, you maybe able to do:

```
if abc.__dict__["report_id"] == 28:
    print("Passed")
else:
    print("Failed")
```

However, if you are iterating through multiple dictionaries or objects, to check which one contains the searched value, you might have to do:

```
for ind_dict in mul_dicts:
    if ind_dict["report_id"] == 28:
        print("Passed")
    else:
        print("Failed")
```

similarly:

```
for ind_obj in mul_objs:
    if ind_obj.__dict__["report_id"] == 28:
        print("Passed")
    else:
        print("Failed")
```

**If you specify your question more then it will be easier to answer your question.**

Comment: Thanks for you reply !!! To be more specific the output where its stored is of type None.TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'. So how to iterate over none type to find the value of report id ?

Comment: None type in python is null value called None itself. It's not stored at None because None is a value, not a placeholder; you can't store anything at None (or as None for that matter). Can you mention what code returned the first output or what is the source of that text?